# Get Length of array JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xamarin

How can I get the length of a JSON Array I get using json.net in C#? After sending a SOAP call I get a JSON string as answer, I use json.net to parse it.

Example of the json I got:

```
{"JSONObject": [
    {"Id":"ThisIsMyId","Value":"ThisIsMyValue"},
    {"Id":"ThisIsMyId2","Value":"ThisIsMyValue2"}
]}
```

And I parse it and write it in console:

```
var test = JObject.Parse (json);
Console.WriteLine ("Id: {0} Value: {1}", (string)test["JSONObject"][0]["Id"], (string)test["JSONObject"][0]["Value"]);
```

This works like a spell, only I don't know the length of the `JSONObject`, but I need to do it in a for loop. I only have no idea how I can get the length of `test["JSONObject"]`

But something like `test["JSONObject"].Length` would be too easy I guess :(..

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can cast the object to a `JArray` and then use the `Count` property, like so:

```
JArray items = (JArray)test["JSONObject"];
int length = items.Count;
```

You can then loop the items as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    var item = (JObject)items[i];
    //do something with item
}
```

---

According to Onno (OP), you can also use the following:

```
int length = test["JSONObject"].Count();
```

However, I have not personally confirmed that this will work

Comment: Don't you need to cast to `JArray` for that?

Comment: I tried that, as I seen that somewhere else. But somewhy I did not try Count() instead, what seems to work.
I'm very sorry for my stupidity :O

Comment: @Onno: Are you saying that `Count()` works? If so I can update the answer

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it works. Count gives me an error in the compiler

Comment: Use ".Count", not ".Count()"

Comment: If the json string includes both objects (with curly brackets {}) and arrays (with square brackets [])...I found using JObject worked with both types.  JArray only worked with arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and cleanest way I found:

```
int length = test["JSONObject"].Count;
```

Comment: This returns the number of `JTokens` which in some cases might NOT be the expected size of the array

Answer (score 2):

You can use below line to get the length of JSON Array in .Net (`JArray`) .

```
 int length = ((JArray)test["jsonObject"]).Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
var test= ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)json).Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me supposing the json data is in a json file.
In this case, .Length works but no intellisence is available:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string jsonFilePath = "C:\\folder\\jsonLength.json";
        var configFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var d = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(configFile);

        var jsonObject = d["JSONObject"];
        int jsonObjectLength = jsonObject.Length;
        return View(jsonObjectLength);
    }
```