# How to Count Data From Json in c# in MultiDimention?

Tags: c#, json

I want to count all data using C# from this JSON

```
[
  {
    "p_id": "0001",
    "p_name": "Tester"
  },
  {
    "p_id": "197921",
    "p_name": "Kanza"
  }
]
```

How to determine that in this JSON there are 2 objects?

Comment: This is a JSON array. its length will get you the answer you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Length of array JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025174/get-length-of-array-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can do something like the below.

```
  var jsonstring = "[{'p_id': '0001','p_name': 'Tester'},{'p_id': '197921','p_name': 'Kanza'}]";
  var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonstring);
  int length = json.Count;
```

length will give you the number of items in your JSON array. Proof is below
[image: Proof of length of JSON object]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length like this:

`var jsonstring = "[{'p_id': '0001','p_name': 'Tester'},{'p_id': '197921','p_name': 'Kanza'}]";
int length = ((JArray)jsonstring).Count;`